# Delete duplicates in postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-9.3, sql-delete

I want to delete all but one row for a given duplicate "external_id". The query below takes about two minutes to run for my table of 5,000,000 rows, and I feel like there's got to be a quicker way of performing this task. "id" is the primary key, and "external_id" is a btree indexed column:

```
delete from posts p1 using (select distinct on (1)
        external_id, id
        from posts
        order by 1 desc, 2 desc) p_recent 
    where p1.external_id = p_recent.external_id
    and p1.id != p_recent.id;
```

How can I improve the performance of this query?

EDIT: QUERY PLAN BELOW:

```
Delete on posts p1  (cost=2322413.28..2673548.11 rows=5583248 width=45) (actual time=148064.026..148064.026 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=2322413.28..2673548.11 rows=5583248 width=45) (actual time=148064.025..148064.025 rows=0 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: ((p_recent.external_id)::text = (p1.external_id)::text)
         Join Filter: (p1.id <> p_recent.id)
         ->  Subquery Scan on p_recent  (cost=1565918.17..1649666.91 rows=5583249 width=54) (actual time=80975.573..98202.920 rows=5947083 loops=1)
               ->  Unique  (cost=1565918.17..1593834.42 rows=5583249 width=15) (actual time=80975.561..95891.264 rows=5947083 loops=1)
                     ->  Sort  (cost=1565918.17..1579876.30 rows=5583249 width=15) (actual time=80975.560..93768.105 rows=5947083 loops=1)
                           Sort Key: posts.external_id, posts.id
                           Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 153984kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on posts  (cost=0.00..653989.49 rows=5583249 width=15) (actual time=0.014..10314.089 rows=5947083 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=653989.49..653989.49 rows=5583249 width=21) (actual time=38966.573..38966.573 rows=5947083 loops=1)
               Buckets: 4096  Batches: 256  Memory Usage: 1017kB
               ->  Seq Scan on posts p1  (cost=0.00..653989.49 rows=5583249 width=21) (actual time=0.028..35863.561 rows=5947083 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 148084.796 ms
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: 5000 rows before or after the delete? How many rows are deleted? Other indexes? Foreign keys? Other constraints? Triggers? Other depending objects? Concurrent load? Your version of Postgres? It depends on all these details that are not in your question.

Comment: The aggregating subquery could force a tablescan on the outer query. I don't even know if adequate statistics can be used for the delete-loop in this case. But still: a few minutes for 5K rows seems way too slow (even my Raspberry with 500MB mem is faster...)

Comment: Sorry guys! This was supposed to say 5 million rows, i dropped a few zeros there :-/ 
Version: Postgres 9.3 as mentioned in the tags, I did mention all indexes, and I'm joining a table against itself, but no foreign keys given the nature of the query. As mentioned originally, "id" is a primary key, which means that it is indexed and unique. "external_id" is an indexed column. 
In this case the absence of information implies that it doesn't exist: no triggers, no concurrent load, running on ubuntu 12.04 and a decently powerful server.

Comment: @jjanes added query plan

Comment: The two seqscans + sort are suspect. Did you analyze after adding the index ?

Comment: @wildplasser wow, thank you! It turns out I did not properly index external_id. I must added an index to it and my version control script didn't realize that the index needed to be added. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of just adding some indexes, you could model your data. (external_id appears to be a FK to some other table. Unfortunately, it would still need the index to be added manually)

Comment: Your disk sort is very slow.  Is your temp tablespace going over a network drive or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DELETE from posts del 
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM posts ex
        WHERE ex.external_id = del.external_id
        AND ex.id < del.id -- if you want to keep the lowest id
        -- AND ex.id > del.id -- if you want to keep the highest id
        );
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - this takes 90 seconds vs my original query which takes 140 seconds, so definitely an improvement!

Comment: Both queries could benefit from an index on {external_id} (or even a unique index on {external_id,id} ) UPDATE: I see external_id already has an index.

Comment: "id" is a primary key, so I *think* it should be indexed as well?

Comment: Yes, primary keys are unique, and unique forces an index to be created. After the creation of an (additional) index, statistics for the indexed fields should be initialised by running `vacuum analyze tablename (columname1, columnnname2, ...)`

Comment: @mgoldwasser   A multicolumn index on (external_id, id) can do things that the two independent indexes cannot do.

Comment: Yes, that's what I proposed in the second comment to this answer, too. (but it depends on the distribution, and the data model is still unknown)

Comment: This answer helped a lot, however ultimately I decided it made the most sense to change the model, per @wildplasser suggestion. external_id is now the primary key and I can "upsert" using that.