# Find duplicate rows and keep the latest one, delete the rest

Tags: postgresql

For example, [row 1] and [row 3] have duplicate values on column A and column B, I need to delete [row 1], any one know how to do in PostgreSQL? (or other SQL server..)

```
           [column A]    [column B]
[row 1]    "/100/"       "0.gif"
[row 2]    "/101/"       "0.gif"
[row 3]    "/100/"       "0.gif"
[row 4]    "/100/"       "1.gif"
```

This question is similar to [Delete duplicated old rows and keep only latest mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306084/delete-duplicated-old-rows-and-keep-only-latest-mysql) but the code there is not working in Postgres(9.1.9)

Comment: How would you identify the "latest" row? Is there a datetime field to use?

Comment: More questions of this kind: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=postgresql+delete+duplicate

Comment: Thanks, there is no any datetime field, but a increasing id field, the greater number is the latest.

Comment: Found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23956441/641484 solved my question.